# Searching to End of String in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract all sequences of '1's from a string of binary digits (0 and 1) and get them into a `list`. 
For example the string may be of the form `001111000110000111111`. And I am looking for a list that looks like this `["1111", "11", "111111"]`.

I am using the python `findall` function with the following `([1]+?)0`. However, it does not match the last sequence of 1's since that ends with a `EOS` rather than a '0'. I have tried to use `([1]+?)0|$` to try to capture the `EOS` as a valid delimited.

But that fails too.
 Any help appreciated.

Comment: remove the `0` from the regex

Comment: you may just use `'1+'` regex (if you need a regex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Matching**: To match one or more `1`s, use `1+` regex.

**Splitting**: You may split with 1 or more `0`s and remove empty elements.

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/sH8MX3):

```
import re
s = '001111000110000111111'
print(re.findall('1+', s))                   # ['1111', '11', '111111']
print([x for x in re.split('0+', s) if x])   # ['1111', '11', '111111']
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Worked great .. i guess I over complicated my RE!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying:

```
([1]+?)0
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7lN1/1)

```
([1]+?)0|$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7lN1/2)

What will work:

```
(1+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7lN1/3)

Comment: even the capture group isn't necessary... `re.findall` will give identical results with `1+`

Comment: Thanks Nehal .. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex you're looking for is:

```
1+(?!\0)
```

i.e. match one or more 1s which aren't followed by a 0.

The one you have is specifically looking for ones that are followed by 0s.

you can play around with regexs on various jsfiddle like sites, with interactive explanations of what they're doing. ex:

https://regex101.com/r/qY4iN9/1